# Given $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x-b}=0$, $\{a,b\}\subset \mathbb R^+$, show the roots are real and within defined intervals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Given: $\{a,b\}\subset \mathbb R^+$, $P(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x-b}=0.$ (**correction**: last term is $\frac{1}{x{\color{red}+}b})$
>
> Show: all roots of $P(x)$ are real, one in the interval $(-b,0)$ and the other in the interval $(0,a)$.

Question asked in an entrance exam.

**My attempt:** developing $P(x)$, we get to
$$x^2-\frac{2}{3}(a+b)x+\frac{ab}{3}=0$$
with discriminant defined by

$$\Delta=\frac{4}{9}(a+b)^2-\frac{4}{3}ab=\frac{4}{9}((a+b)^2-3ab)=\frac{4}{9}(a^2+b^2-ab)$$
As it is easy to show that $a^2+b^2-ab\ge 0$ it follows that $\Delta\ge 0$. This solves the first part of the question.

I tried, unsuccessfully, to solve the second part, which asked to show that the roots are within two specific intervals. Hints and full answers are welcome.

**Edit 1.** The term $\frac{1}{x-b}$ is, most likely, $\frac{1}{x+b}$. See comments below for an explanation.

Comment: I think you should check the original problem statement.  As you copied it here, it is not correct.  Possible the term $1/(x-b)$ should have  been $1/(x+b)$.

Comment: @hardmath, you are right, the statement I presented was copied from a book. I searched the original exam (IME exam 1976/77) and by chance I found the original question with an answer. The statement in the material is identical to the one I transcribed here, but there is a note stating that the solution assumes $1/(x+b)$ instead of $1/(x-b)$. As this question was not considered invalid, perhaps the original text had $1/(x-b)$ and the correction was given in the classroom during the exam (a guess). I will, later on, transcribe the solution presented there which uses calculus arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is not true. When a is smaller than b, consider the quadratic function you get , let x equal to 0, a and b, you will know that one root lies between 0 and a, another root lies between a and b. When a is bigger than b, it is similar.

Comment: Underlying your explanation that "the problem is not true" is the symmetry between the roles of $a$ and $b$.  As you say, "When $a$ is bigger than $b$, it is similar" to the case when $a$ is smaller than $b$.  Yet the problem as stated draws a conclusion (one root in $(-b,0)$ and the other in $(0,a)$) in which the roles of $a$ and $b$ are not interchangeable.

Comment: I don't use the symmetry between a and b. I discussed about which one is bigger in order to show where are the two roots. Then I get their locations. However, my conclusion is different from that in the provlem. So I think the problem has some mistakes.

Comment: I realize that you don't use the symmetry between $a$ and $b$, or more precisely, between the roles they play in the problem setup (both are positive numbers, and the terms $1/(x-a)$ plus $1/(x-b)$ commute if $a,b$ are exchanged).   However I thought I should point out the symmetry to show that yes, the problem is wrong because it proposes that even though the roles of $a,b$ are interchangeable, a conclusion is proposed that has $a,b$ playing *distinguised* roles.

Answer (score 2):

I am using calculus. Please tell me if it is not allowed in the exam, then I can post an alternate solution.

Case $1$ : $P(x) = \frac 1{x} + \frac 1{x-a} + \frac 1{x-b} = 0$ (This was done *before* the edit, but is included for completeness)

$P(x)$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb R \backslash\{0,a,b\}$. Without loss of generality, let us assume that $0 < a < b$. Then, in the interval $(0,a)$,  note that as $x \to 0^+$, $P(x)$ eventually becomes positive, and as $x \to a^-$, $P(x)$ eventually becomes negative, and therefore, by the intermediate value theorem, $P(x)$ has a root in $(0,a)$.

Similarly, in the interval $(a,b)$,  note that as $x \to a^+$, $P(x)$ eventually becomes positive, and as $x \to b^-$, $P(x)$ eventually becomes negative, and therefore, by the intermediate value theorem, $P(x)$ has a root in $(a,b)$.

Finally, we note that for $x < 0$, all three quantities $\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{x-a},\frac{1}{x-b}$ are strictly negative, hence their sum is strictly negative. Similarly, for $x>b$, the sum is strictly positive. Hence, no roots lie in these regions.

Furthermore, $P(x)$ has no complex roots. To see this, note that by taking the common denominator, $$\frac 1{x} + \frac 1{x-a} + \frac 1{x-b} = \frac{3x^2+x(-2a-2b)+ab}{x(x-a)(x-b)}$$

Therefore, $P(x)=0$ precisely when $3x^2 + x(-2a-2b) + ab = 0$. This can have at most two roots in the entire complex plane because it has degree $2$. However, we have already located those roots above, showing that there are no other roots available.

Therefore , there are precisely two roots of this equation, both real.

Case $2$ : $P(x) = \frac 1x + \frac 1{x-a} + \frac 1{x+b} = 0$.

We will use calculus, yet again. Now, we have the following regions to consider :

- $x<-b$ : Each of $\frac 1{x},\frac{1}{x-a},\frac 1{x+b}<0$, therefore there is no root in this interval.
- $-b<x<0$ : As $x \to -b^+$, $P(x) \to +\infty$, while as $x \to 0^-$, $P(x) \to -\infty$. Therefore, by the intermediate value theorem, there is a root in $(-b,0)$.
- $0<x<a$ : As $x \to 0^+$, $P(x) \to +\infty$, while as $x \to a^-$, $P(x) \to -\infty$. Therefore, by the intermediate value theorem, there is a root in $(0,a)$.
- $x>a$ : Each of $\frac 1x , \frac 1{x-a},\frac{1}{x+b}$ is positive in this interval, hence there is no root.

However, similar to the argument in Case $1$, $P(x)$ has only two roots in total : and we found both above. Hence, these *are* the roots of the equation. Furthermore, if one needs to find them, then one can use the quadratic formula on the equation derived as the numerator of $P(x)$ after one takes the common denominator.

Comment: No. This exam considers algebra precalculus. But your argument is nice and is worth keeping here.

Comment: Yes, but somewhere I find ti difficult to recollect, how we used to prove existence of roots in precalculus algebra. I mean, if you say, show that a root of some equation lies between some two given points, then what else, other than the IVT, could I use to show just the existence of the root? For one, it may not be easy to compute the root, for example say something like $x = \cos x$ has a root in $[-2,2]$.

Comment: See comments below the problem statement. The "official" solution uses calculus arguments (I will transcribe it later on) but states that the last term is not $\frac{1}{x-b}$ but  $\frac{1}{x+b}$. This exam is known for being very tough... and often asks material beyond the scope of the official syllabus.